# Appending React component without ANY redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using `ReactDOM.render` to render into an element, but it completely overwrites existing nodes within it. I don't want to tie any redux-like state functionality, I just want to render to a string and append to a element. Is this possible?

I suspect people will tell me to just use states and what-not, but I guess my follow-up question to that would be, I have a element that will have hundreds/thousands of images, will it re-render everytime using React? Will manipulating a state with thousands of objects be slow?

Comment: If there's thousands of images in component I guess you should make a sub component for that functionality

Comment: @Chathuranga94 Could you point me to some material that would teach me how to do that efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example of products being listed:

https://jsfiddle.net/pf7z8z4m/12/

```
class Product extends React.Component{

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return (this.props.product !== nextProps.product)
  }

  render(){
    console.log('rendering product '+this.props.product.name)
    return (<li>
      <h4>{this.props.product.name}</h4>
      <img src={this.props.product.img} alt={this.props.product.name}/>
      </li>)
  }
}

class ProductList extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const items = this.props.products.map((product)=>
            <ul key={product.id}>
        <Product product={product}/>
      </ul>)
    return (<ul>{items}</ul>)
  }

}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {products:[]}

    //following is just a simple simulation of products being added to the list through time
    setTimeout(
        ()=>{this.setState({products:[...this.state.products,
        {id:1,name:'Product A', img:'productA.png'}]})},
      1000
        )
    setTimeout(
        ()=>{this.setState({products:[...this.state.products,
        {id:2,name:'Product B', img:'productB.png'}]})},
      3000
        )
    setTimeout(
        ()=>{this.setState({products:[...this.state.products,
        {id:3,name:'Product C', img:'productC.png'}]})},
      5000
        )
    }

  render(){
    return (<ProductList products={this.state.products}/>)
  }
}

React.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

New elements (products) are being added to the list regularly, but not causing re-render on the rest.

The method shouldComponentUpdate on Product is controlling that. Another option is to extend React.PureComponent.

Take a look at this doc:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html